# How to Reset/Clear selected cells

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, reset

In Google sheets, is it possible to clear selected cells???
when I say "clear" I would like the cells to restore there default **font** (color/size/style), reset the cell **background**, reset any cell **border** style, reset the **math** functions on the cell, delete any **notes** or **comments** add to the cell.

I try to select a few cell and click the "delete" button, that this will only remove the cell value.

Answer (score 1):

yes, that's possible. select cells you want to reset and press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`\`**</kbd> which will handle formatting.

then press <kbd>**`BACKSPACE`**</kbd> or <kbd>**`DELETE`**</kbd> for content removal

and you can enter note edit mode with <kbd>**`SHIFT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`F2`**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks - This will not reset (delete) the cell value (content) - But it will remove all formats. This is good enough, because I can later just click `delete` key.